# To which all factors chemical equilibrium is directly proportional to?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, equilibrium

The equilibrium constant is directly proportional to the concentration. why it is so?  Is chemical equilibrium dependent on temperature and other such factors? Then why we only focus on concentration?

Comment: Is the equilibriation happening at fixed temperature or fast enough that the temperature isn't changing appreciably over that time? Same for other variables.

Comment: fixed temperature

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?